# Why no more mocks in Arquillian?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mockito, ejb, jboss-arquillian

If you go to [Arquillian's home page](http://arquillian.org/) it says: `No more mocks.`, but if I have EJB 1 that injects EJB 2 and I want to test EJB 1, how do I simulate EJB 2 if I don't mock it? Is Arquillian used for integration and not unit testing? Why is it a bad practice to mock in Arquillian and what's the alternative?

Comment: "Is Arquillian used for integration and not unit testing?" Yes

Comment: I like how Arquillian allows me to access EJBs in a container without restarting it (specifically, I'm using Wildfly), how can achieve that in unit tests if I don't use Arquillian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arquillian is indeed used for integration testing and not unit testing.

It's somewhat of a bad practice to mock extensively in Arquillian, exactly for this reason. It largely defeats the purpose of using Arquillian in the first place.

That said, mocking in Arquillian for the situation you described is reasonably easy. As the default mode in Arquillian is for you to provide micro archives build with shrinkwrap, you can simply replace EJB2 with a mock version when creating your archive.

For instance:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> deployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
            .addClass(com.real.EJB1.class)
            .addClass(com.example.mock.EJB2.class)
        ;
    }

    // ..
}
```

Since `EJB1` would not depend on the actual class type of `EJB2` but only on its (simple) name or interface, you can just swap it out when creating your test.

Comment: If you want different isolation level by ISTQB V model . should mock some SUT dependencies . for example dependencies from other module should mock on some  isolation level because you just need test your code with DB and your own module EJBs .